# Arrange Columns in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` that is populated by a stored proc.  Typically I would reorder the columns using the 'Edit Columns' dialog but this `datagridview` is being used to display data from different sources so I can't do that.

I have figured out how to rename the Headers and make certain columns Frozen but how do I change the display order on them?

Comment: you could use DataGridView.Columns[index].DisplayIndex = 0;

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With the [DisplayIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex.aspx) property

```
myGridView.Columns["myFirstCol"].DisplayIndex = 0;
myGridView.Columns["mySecondCol"].DisplayIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you set the [DisplayIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex.aspx) for the columns?

Answer (score -1):

```
 grid.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
```