# Disable datagridview automatic ordering VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

In some cases (I believe when inner join is used) datagridview does not represent correctly the column order populated from SQL query.

For example, I query the table columns in this order:

```
Select Booking_ID, Client_Name, Room_ID
```

although SQL return columns in correct order, however datagridview displays columns automatically in different order:

```
Room_ID || Booking_ID || Client_Name
```

The question is, how to disable this automatic column horizontal ordering, so datagridview displays the table exactly how SQL does?

I am using datasource method to fill the datagrid.

```
SQLDA = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd)
SQLDataset = New DataSet
SQLDA.Fill(SQLDataset)
Form2.DGVData.DataSource = SQLDataset.Tables(0)
```

In most cases this problem is not present, and datagridview shows the table exactly as SQL does.

Thank you in advance.

PS: I would post the images but I'm not allowed since 10 reputation is required.

Comment: As Question is not clear....How you filling datagridview ? show the code also .. if your using datasource method to fill then try to use `order by` in `query`,i.e `Select Booking_ID, Client_Name, Room_ID from yourTable order by Client_Name`

Comment: Yes I am using datasource method.

    `SQLDA = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd)
    SQLDataset = New DataSet
    SQLDA.Fill(SQLDataset)
    Form2.DGVData.DataSource = SQLDataset.Tables(0)`

Comment: show your code to fill datagridview  edit your question

Comment: 'order by' command order the rows, in my case row order is not the problem, instead column order is incorrect as I explained above.

Comment: To answer your question, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334983/best-way-to-disable-the-column-header-sorting-in-datagridview).. To setthe Display Index, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168404/arrange-columns-in-a-datagridview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, but should work:

```
dgvDataGridView.Columns("Booking_ID").DisplayIndex = 0
dgvDataGridView.Columns("Client_Name").DisplayIndex = 1
dgvDataGridView.Columns("Room_ID").DisplayIndex = 2
'...
```

Comment: While this solution works - it is a manual declarative process, it would be better to force the datagridview to not perform this nasty behavior in the first place.