# How to Disable DataGridView from automatically reordering columns when bound to dataset table

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview and I am binding to a dataset object that was created with the visual studio designer. 
As a simple example:
My query of a SQL database returns my columns in order :  ID, NAME, GRADE - just fine, if I query manually and return and bind no problems columns show up in the order they were returned from the query. 
However I am required to use the dataset object. When the DataGridView is bound to the table inside the dataset (even though the table columns are in the right order ) the datagridview decides on its own to reorder the columns!! Aaargh!!

**How can I prevent this ugly behavior** ?

I am not looking at naming my columns and setting the ordinal positions as is posted here:

[Disable datagridview automatic ordering VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162043/disable-datagridview-automatic-ordering-vb-net)

That 'answer' does not prevent the behavior but forces known column names[Hard Coding] and setting ordinals for any and all datgridviews.

CODE EXAMPLE:

```
   Dim dt As appDataSet.booksDataTable = New appDataSet.booksDataTable
   BooksTableAdapter.FillByRecipeID(dt, ID)


' This just checks for a particular field and uses a drop down instead. 
' You can exclude it the behaviour is the same.

dgvExample.AutoGenerateColumns = False
If dgvExample.Columns.Count < 1 Then
    CreateDataGridColumns(dt)
End If

dgvExample.DataSource = Nothing
dgvExample.DataSource = bsBooks
```

Comment: Do you have code illustrating this behavior?  The DataSet does little but store datatables, so it is unlikely to be at fault

Comment: @Plutonix - I do not think it is the datset perse - I think it is the handling the datagridview has when bound to the object - which is why I asked How to prevent the datagridview from behaving this way. As I said in my comments everything is in the right order before it gets to the datgridview. String values are placed after Integers when bound to a dataset object from my observations.

Comment: Drill into the queries in those adapters - the DGV shows the columns in the same order as in the DataTables.  The DataTables contain the columns in the order specified by the SQL.  The Wizard did something different than you want, I would suspect.

Comment: A quick test using a DataAdapter (no wizard) and varying SQL, the columns show up in the order I specify, dataset or no dataset.

Comment: @Plutonix - my SQL comes back in the dataset correctly (I wrote the query)  - I look at the Tables there - the order is correct. I look at dt and the columns are correct. I CreateDataGridColumns(dt)  or not .. and the datagridview does what it wants integers first strings last.

Comment: Its your *strongly typed* DataSet. No matter what order you specify in the SQL, it returns the columns in the order they appear in the table def.  If you preview the data from the form try item, you can see that it uses your SQL to know *which* columns to return, but uses the order they are listed in the table/def.

Comment: @Plutonix please post as answer - you are correct - the dataset is forcing this behaviour.

Comment: Leave it open for a while. Someone might know a way to force a View onto things somewhere (as if another element was needed with them).[jmcilhinney](http://stackoverflow.com/users/584183/jmcilhinney) comes to mind

Comment: Your posted code is missing some information.   It creates and fills a `DataTable` (dt) using `BooksTableAdapter.FillByRecipeID`.  Then it executes `dgvExample.DataSource = bsBooks`.  Presumably `bsBooks` is a `BindingSource` instance, but you do not show how that `BindingSource` is configured;  does it even use the `DataTable` created in the shown code as its DataSource?

Comment: @TnTinMn sorry you can either place dt as the source for the dgvExample Datasource or place bsBooks.DataSource = dt before assignment to the dgvExample in either case it does not change. Plutonix is correct the Strongly Typed DataSet has that column ordering . I still do not know how to force it to ignore the dataset column ordering .The way binding to dataset works is horrible because just adding a column in the designer throws everything off. My Query is how I would like things - not by dataset.

Comment: OK, it is the strongly typed `appDataSet.booksDataTable` that is setting the column order.  You can set the DGV column display order either by changing the returned `appDataSet.booksDataTable` column order by using the [DataColumn.SetOrdinal Method (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.setordinal(v=vs.110).aspx) or by setting the DGV's Column.DisplayIndex property for each column.  Typically, people modify the DGV Column.DisplayIndex property as it allows for positioning unbound columns.

Comment: @TnTinMn Both of these methods are after the fact and require me to name the columns [HardCode]. My query is already set in the order I want it, if I add a column to the query or change the order of the query fields then I must also change it in the code - I do not want to do that. It is as if the DataGridView is setting up columns from the dataset before the query even comes back. I should be able to prevent that behavior. But maybe not - and I am just stuck.

Comment: `I should be able to prevent that behavior.` You are using a tool to create the strongly typed DataSet.  The creators of the tool default the strongly typed DataTable's column order to the DB's column order (a reasonable assumption), yet give you the ability to reorder the columns via cut/paste in the DataSet designer.  You are expecting the columns to reorder based on the DataAdapter query used; that is not the way it works as each table is a set design.  If you need multiple column orders, make copies of the table in the designer and set your required order on each table.